# apply PageTransformer to PagerView as soon as possible

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a PageTransfomer applied to a ViewPager, it works great but I want to launch the page's transformation as soon as I set the PageTransformer to the ViewPager.
I already tried:

- setCurrentItem(int)
- setCurrentItem(int, true)
- beginFakeDrag(), fakeDragBy(float), endFakeDrag()
- invalidate()
- getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()

I've tried all these in the onCreate of my activity but maybe I'm wrong.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these things:

1. Put the code in `onPostCreate()`
2. Put the code in a handler; i.e. `new Handler().post(new Runnable() { /* your code */ });`

Comment: Thanks it works with the Handler and beginFakeDrag(), fakeDragBy(0f), endFakeDrag()

Answer (score 5):

Based on Oleg's answer is used the code below for my app.

My addition is to check the returned result of `beginFakeDrag()` inside `_invalidatePageTransformer`.

I call `sendInvalidatePageTransformer()` from inside

- `onConfigurationChanged()` when the orientation changed
- inside the `LoaderCallback<Cursor>`-methods in my Fragment

  ```
  private Handler handler = new Handler()
  {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg)
          {
                  switch(msg.what)
                  {
                          case 0:
                                  _invalidatePageTransformer();
                                  break;
                  }
          }
  };

  private void _invalidatePageTransformer()
  {
          //no need to invalidate if we have no adapter or no items
          if (this.getAdapter() != null && this.getAdapter().getCount() > 0)
          {
                  //import check here, only fakeDrag if "beginFakeDrag()" returns true
                  if (this.beginFakeDrag())
                  {
                          this.fakeDragBy(0f);
                          this.endFakeDrag();
                  }
          }
  }

  public void sendInvalidatePageTransformer()
  {
          this.handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
  }
  ```

**EDIT:** Note: This code is located inside a custom ViewPager-subclass