# On viewpager, Setadapter and SetCurrentItem remove transformations set by pagetransform

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using viewpager in my application to dynamically load views and scroll them horizontally. I have also used pageTransform to scale the next and previous view. Have taken the code from

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Each of the next view is dependent on the user responses of the previous view. On each OnPageSelected, I am loading the next view

```
    mPagerAdapter.addView(ViewToBeAdded, AddAtPostion); //Empty previous view holder
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

**Problem Step 1 :** Once I do a setAdapter, The entire viewpager scrolls to the first position, (I am not sure why this is happening).

**Problem Step 2 :** To circumvent problem 1, I called

```
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(AddAtPostion, false);.
```

//If I call with second parameter as true, the viewPager scrolls from the first item to current item.

However, When I call this, the transformations set by pageTransform are removed (as the get applied only on scroll), and the previous view holder is displayed without any transformation.

**Problem Step 3 :** To circumvent problem 2, I added the runnable to call a fake drag after setCurrentItem (As Learnt from [apply PageTransformer to PagerView as soon as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282375/apply-pagetransformer-to-pagerview-as-soon-as-possible))

```
private Handler mhandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mrunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
        mViewPager.fakeDragBy(0f);
        mViewPager.endFakeDrag();

    }
};
//Called as mhandler.postDelayed(mrunnable, 10); after setCurrentItem.
```

This does solve my issue of applying transformation. However there is a flash of the empty view holder seen before the transformation gets applied. I am at my wits end. I am a beginner to Android and have no idea how do I solve any of the issues. If problem 1 itself gets solved, I would not have to find workarounds.

Posted below is the code to add a view and inflate the previous view with empty layout

```
public int addView(View v, int position) {

    prevPos = currPos;
    currPos = position;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(prevPos != -1)
    {
        views.set(prevPos, ((View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_template, null, false)));
    }

    views.set(currPos, v);



    return position;
}
```

Logcat :

```
06-20 16:50:54.890: D/AndroidRuntime(8810): Shutting down VM
06-20 16:50:54.890: W/dalvikvm(8810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bc51f8)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.endFakeDrag(ViewPager.java:2234)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at mpkgname.mactivityname$1.run(mactivityname.java:202)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-20 16:50:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8810):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 16:51:19.992: D/dalvikvm(8810): Debugger has detached; object registry had 658 entries
```

Comment: are you called setAdapter on every page change? That means every time you are adding a new adapter to the viewpager so it scrolls to the first page and the whole viewpager is reloaded.