# Android PageTransformer kills View functionality

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I am using [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) to have a `ViewPager` with tabs in an Android layout.

My `ViewPager` custom adapter is the following:

```
private static class SlidingPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements IconTabProvider {

    private final List<Tab> mItems;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public SlidingPagerAdapter(Context context, List<Tab> tabs) {
        mItems = tabs;
        mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
        return v == (View) obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Tab data = mItems.get(position);
        View child = mInflator.inflate(data.mLayoutResource, container, false);
        container.addView((View) child, 0);
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position).mIconResource;
    }

}
```

The problem arises when I set a `PageTransformer` to the `ViewPager`. As a test I used [ZoomOutPageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) provided in the Android docs.

When the child view from the ViewPager is first loaded, all works fine. I can click items and the views are updated. But after the first time I scroll through the ViewPager, the child views just stop rendering properly. If I click on an item, I can feel haptic feedback and click sounds but the view remains in its previous state.

I have tried invalidating the View every time there is a change in the ViewPager, but this hasn't helped.

There are [similar problems when using a ListView inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223254/listview-inside-viewpager-wont-scroll-when-applying-a-pagetransformer), so I tried setting the views that are out of view as GONE, but this hasn't worked either.

Comment: version of android where you are experiencing the issue?

Comment: Lollipop 5.0.1.  I haven't tried other devices yet

Comment: did you disable the hardware acceleration ?

Comment: Yes, I tried hardware on and off

Comment: same here, the page transformer works fine when the device is under api 21, but stops completely working if the device is on lollipop, i have not found any solution yet...

Comment: Same here, I've just started a new app and as soon as I scroll a few times I start seeing strange things, like the views not being rendered properly

Comment: @liarspocker did you find any solutions for it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I was able to fix it by following the answer on this SO question: [apply PageTransformer to PagerView as soon as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282375/apply-pagetransformer-to-pagerview-as-soon-as-possible) Except I used .0001f in fakeDragBy()

Hacky, but it worked.